# Can the Request class requestId and/or quiddity be used to detect trigger retry in AllOrNothing=false use case

Tags: trigger

[Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) states

> If a DML call is made with partial success allowed, triggers are fired during the first attempt and are fired again during subsequent attempts. Because these trigger invocations are part of the same transaction, static class variables that are accessed by the trigger aren't reset.

[Bulk DML Exception Handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_bulk_exceptions.htm) describes this in more detail

A common pattern to prevent recursion in triggers is to use static collections of Ids to denote records already processed that should be ignored if the trigger is re-entered (perhaps due to a Flow, PB, or WFR update). For example, to prevent a callout from occurring twice.

But static variables aren't reset when a trigger DML retry is done so it is possible that during the retry, you'll skip an action

There are some solutions to this issue:

- [Mine (works, but not so great)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/202668/2602)
- [Charles T (better)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/202670/2602)
- [Derek (best)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/304507/2602)

I got to thinking. Could we exploit the [`Request` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Request.htm?q=quiddity) values for `requestId` and `quiddity` to detect the retry use case?

Comment: [My two cents](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/316411/2984) regarding recursion. DML only on changed records, or resetting the flag properly, are the two best ways to avoid infinite recursion. My method of avoiding recursion is 100% foolproof, regardless of whatever flows, PB, or triggers you might add later, as long as you follow either of those design patterns.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I knew you'd weigh in with this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sadly NO

Given a trigger

```
trigger AccountRequestIdTrigger on Account (before update) {

    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'RequestId = ' + Request.getCurrent().getRequestId() + 
                                   ' quiddity=' + Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity());
    for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {Trigger.new[i].addError('failing record 0, expect a retry');}
    }
}
```

And invoked by

```
Database.update([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 2],false); // allow partial success
```

- The `Request.getCurrent().getRequestId()` returns an invariant value on the initial DML attempt as well as subsequent retries of the failed records. *Not surprising since the doc states that the retry occurs in the same transaction and if requestId changed across the transaction, the event logs would be hard to correlate*
- The `Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity()` is also invariant

### Debug log excerpt

```
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q030000005eIW|AccountRequestIdTrigger on Account trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/AccountRequestIdTrigger
RequestId = 4pCdJYC7q3xaNOV2atCYoV quiddity=ANONYMOUS
Number of retries: 1|Number of rows: 2|Number of rows with errors: 1
RequestId = 4pCdJYC7q3xaNOV2atCYoV quiddity=ANONYMOUS
Number of retries: 2|Number of rows: 2|Number of rows with errors: 1
RequestId = 4pCdJYC7q3xaNOV2atCYoV quiddity=ANONYMOUS
```

It would be nice if there were a `Request.getCurrent().isBulkDmlRetry()` method